# Change column name and data type in one command oracle

Tags: oracle

Change column name and data type in one command or one statement in oracle

I Tried to rename the name of the column but I wanna change name and data type at the same time in one command

Comment: for taht you use alter table MODIFY see https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-alter-table-modify-column/

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: you can't, as far as I can tell.

A little bit longer demo. This is sample table with some sample data:

```
SQL> desc temp;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENO                                                NUMBER
 ESAL                                               NUMBER

SQL> select * From temp;

       ENO       ESAL
---------- ----------
        10        100
```

## Step-by-step:

Renaming a column:

```
SQL> alter table temp rename column eno to empno;

Table altered.
```

Modifying its datatype won't work; column has to be empty:

```
SQL> alter table temp modify empno varchar2(10);
alter table temp modify empno varchar2(10)
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype


SQL>
```

OK, so let's truncate it and try again - now it works:

```
SQL> truncate table temp;

Table truncated.

SQL> alter table temp modify empno varchar2(10);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

---

## Two modifications in a single step:

I'll recreate table and leave it empty (as you saw, you can't modify its datatype otherwise):

```
SQL> drop table temp;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table temp (eno number, esal number);

Table created.
```

Combine two alters:

```
SQL> alter table temp
  2    rename column eno to empno
  3    modify empno varchar2(10);
alter table temp
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-23290: This operation may not be combined with any other operation


SQL>
```

What does that error mean?

> **Cause**: ALTER TABLE RENAME COLUMN/CONSTRAINT operation was given in conjunction with another ALTER TBALE Operation. This is not allowed.
>
> **Action**: Ensure that RENAME COLUMN/CONSTRAINT is the only operation specified in the ALTER TABLE.

---

So ... nope, that won't work.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I did, Run each command alone.